# Outlook 2007 and 2010 table cell formatting lost with long content

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email

The set up:

```
 <table width="600" >
    <tr>
        <td width="400" rowspan="2" valign="top">
            With very long content here*
        </td>
        <td width="200" valign="top">
            Top-aligned content
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom">
          *Bottom-aligned content loses vertical alignment
             and appears as if valign="middle"              
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Example code is in jsfiddle as it is too long (lots of content needed to trigger the bug).

So see these:

http://jsfiddle.net/webhelpla/XZyg2/ sent as an email looks OK

http://jsfiddle.net/webhelpla/XZyg2/1/ sent as an email: bottom-aligned content is not bottom-aligned anymore.

Any ideas and experience with workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `vertical-align:bottom;` as well,

```
  <td valign="bottom" style='vertical-align:bottom;' >
      *Bottom-aligned content loses vertical alignment
         and appears as if valign="middle"              
   </td>
```

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XZyg2/2/) fiddle. i removed the `rowspan=2` from the td, always use cellpadding in place of that.

Answer (score 0):

Add  table-layout:fixed to the css for the table and see if that helps.  Coder1984 is correct in adding the "style=" tag inside the td since some email clients do better with that....

At any rate, it is very hard to predict how html email will render in various clients.  I use [email on acid](http://emailonacid.com) to check rendering in a wide range of clients, from webmail through email clients to mobile....

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has an issue with content of blocks over a certain size (2300px if I remember correctly).  You *may* be able to avoid the issue with a third cell in your right-hand row:

```
 <table width="600" >
    <tr>
        <td width="400" rowspan="3" valign="top">
            With very long content here*
        </td>
        <!-- Add minimal heights to force the middle row to take the space -->
        <td width="200" valign="top" height="1">
            Top-aligned content
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="page-break:always"><!-- Let's make a page break *here* --></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" height="1">
          *Bottom-aligned content loses vertical alignment
             and appears as if valign="middle"              
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```